# Specifying missing.png in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to handle profile photo uploads in my app. They upload well and resize to the specifications in my model. However, if a User's profile :photo is nil, no matter what I try I can't change the default. Here's the code I want to use:

```
<% if @profile.photo.nil? %>
<%= image_tag "public/images/example.jpg", :html => { :id => "noUserProfile" } %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag @profile.photo.url(:normal) %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried "../public/images/example.jpg" and that doesn't work either even though I have "example.jpg" in my public images folder. When I copy image address in my view, I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/photos/normal/missing.png
```

I added those folders to my app and put a missing.png file in there and nothing. If I go to the above URL I get `No route matches "/photos/normal/missing.png"`

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going on?

**has_attached_file** in Profile model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
  :normal => "153x220#",
  :small => "75x108#" }
```

**add_attachment_photo_to_profile** migration:

```
class AddAttachmentPhotoToProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :profiles, :photo_file_name, :string
    add_column :profiles, :photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :profiles, :photo_file_size, :integer
    add_column :profiles, :photo_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :profiles, :photo_file_name
    remove_column :profiles, :photo_content_type
    remove_column :profiles, :photo_file_size
    remove_column :profiles, :photo_updated_at
  end
end
```

**This is the HTML that's rendered for when the `:photo` exists:**

```
<div class="userSnapshot">
  <div class="smFrame">
    <div class="smUserPhoto">
      <img alt="8217_667699353137_15600054_38423586_7789442_n" src="/system/photos/1/small/8217_667699353137_15600054_38423586_7789442_n.jpg?1316052048" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="findinfo">
    <p><a href="/profiles/1">Name</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the HTML that's rendered for when the `:photo` is nil:**

```
<div class="userSnapshot">
  <div class="smFrame">
    <div class="smUserPhoto">
      <img alt="Missing" src="/photos/small/missing.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="findinfo">
    <p><a href="/profiles/2">Name</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought `has_attached_file` was a model-level "declaration"? Why wouldn't you just say `image_tag 'images/example.jpg'`? Am I totally misunderstanding the code above?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried `image_tag` but that didn't work either. The photos that are showing are saved to `http://localhost:3000/system/photos/:id/:size/xxxxxx`.

Comment: I don't understand. If the profile photo is nil, an `image_tag` should serve an image from `/public/images` just like any other image, and the paperclip directory shouldn't enter into the equation.

Comment: Yeah I don't much get it. I've pasted the HTML that is generated above. You can see what the code shows when there is a `:photo` as well as when the `:photo` is `nil`.

Comment: Does paperclip do something that makes the photo not be nil? It's pretty clear your image_tag for when it's nil isn't rendering. What does your `has_attached_file` look like in the model? Do the [rdocs](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file) help?

Comment: I put the `has_attached_file` in the question. I'm new to programming unfortunately but I'll take a look at the rdocs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the `:default_url` option in the [rdocs](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file), that's why it's rendering as it is. Paperclip handles the cases when there's no attached file.

You can set the default to something different and avoid the extra work in your template.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I tried :default_url earlier but must not have had the proper combination.

Comment: Awesome; glad you worked it out. Sometimes it's just random permutations of what you think might possibly maybe work ;)

Comment: No kidding. Thanks again. Next up: MetaSearch!

Comment: if i were to not change the default_url but just fill in a missing png. where do i place this on the file system, under what folder? Thanks

Comment: @carbonr in tvalent2's example it would be `public/photos/small/missing.jpg`, in newer versions I think the default path changed though.

Comment: @complistic : Your solution worked, but I have a doubt. When we specify ":default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png", I assume "images" folder should be picked from assets. Why do I need to create images under public folder ?

Comment: @furiabhavesh, the default_url just makes the uri the same as you type it, no assets magic going on here... so it's just a static public file. If you wanted to use the assets magic I *think* you could do something like `:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(":style/missing.png")`. I have used something like this in a rails 3.1 project before, but not in rails 4.

Answer (score 15):

I think you want the `exists?` method.

```
if @profile.photo.exists?
```

`@profile.photo.nil?` will always be `false` because it returns the default image when it's missing.

---

**NOTE**: This checks if the really file exists, and can be very slow if you host your images on a CDN.

As a work around you might be able to just check if the database thinks there is a file:

```
if @profile.photo_file_name.present?
```